# Duplicate Class Error when importing Java Twillio Library in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, sdk, duplicates, twilio

When importing the twilio java helper library in Android Studio, I get the following build error:

```
Duplicate class javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor found in modules jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1) and javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar (javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0)
```

Below is my gradle.xml file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.1.11"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
//    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
   implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0@aar') {
      transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "8.27.1"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The twilio line is causing the error. I have tried commenting out the other libraries to see what is causing the duplicate classes, but no luck. I have tried cleaning the project, setting the twilio sdk to transitive, and excluding the duplicate classes, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

The Twilio library you are trying to include there is not built for Android and should not be used in Android applications.

The library makes it easy to call the Twilio REST APIs from an application, however you should not do that from a mobile application. To do so would mean that your mobile application would need to be able to access your account credentials and a malicious user could debug or decompile your app, extract your credentials and use them to abuse your Twilio account.]

Instead of making calls directly to the Twilio API from your Android application, we recommend that you write a server-side application that can contain your credentials safely and make API requests on your behalf. Then you should make requests to your server. This post is a little old now, but still shows what we recommend you do if you want to [use Twilio to send an SMS from Android](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I created a new application to use Twilio in but I am still getting the same duplicate classes error.

Comment: If that new application is an Android application, then this still won't work. Like I said, this library is not built for and not intended for Android development.